# Prove two subgroups have the same order given an equivalence relation.

Tags: group-theory

Let $X$ be the set of all subgroups of a group $G$. The following is an equivalence relation $H$~$K$ where $H=xKx^{-1}$.

Prove: If $H$~$K$, then $|H|=|K|$.

I'm guessing $H$,$K$ are subgroups of a group $G$.  Other than that, I'm not quite sure where to start on this one.  I know that if $|H|=|K|$ then they have the same amount of elements in them but I'm not sure how to prove that given the equivalence relation.

Comment: Try constructing a bijection between $K$ and $H$, i.e. a bijection between $K$ and $xKx^{-1}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The action of a group on a set, and the size of an orbit.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156482/the-action-of-a-group-on-a-set-and-the-size-of-an-orbit)

Answer (score 2):

Check the map $f : K \rightarrow H$ such that $f(a) = xax^{-1}$. It's obviously surjective homomorphism. So if it is injective we are done. Suppose that $a \in \operatorname{Ker}(f)$, then $xax^{-1} = e \Rightarrow xa=x $ (right multiplication by $x$) $\Rightarrow a = e$ (left multiplication by $x^{-1}$). Therefore $f$ is indeed injective, because $\operatorname{Ker}(f) = \{e\}$. Here is the desired bijection.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively check the inverse of the function $f(h)=ghg^{-1}$ is $g^{-1}hg. $ Hence $f$ is a bijection with the appropriate co-domain.