# The action of a group on a set, and the size of an orbit.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This question may be easy to solve with an example, but I am not able to think of any.

Let's say that you have a group G, and a subgroup H, it is show that a the cosets $(aH), a \in G$, form an equivalence relation, so they partition G, but the interesting part in this case is that **every part of the partition has the same amount of elements.**

But let's say you have a set X, which is not a group, but you have a group G, that acts on the group X.

Formally this means that:

$gx\in X, \forall g \in G, \forall x \in X$

$ex=x, \forall x \in X$

$(g_1g_2)x=g_1(g_2x)$.

It can be show that the relation $x_1$~$x_2$, if there is a g such that $gx_1=x_2$, exists. Hence since we have an equivalence relation we get a partition of X, and we call these partitions for **orbits in X under G**.

**My question is: Are these orbits/partitions of the same size like in the coset case?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, in general they aren't.

**Easy example:** Let $\mathbb R^\ast$ (the group of nonzero real numbers under multiplication) act on the set $\mathbb R$ via multiplication.  There are exactly two orbits, $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$.

One thing to point out though it that while cosets of $H$ can be acted on by $G$, this action is transitive and has only one orbit, so the cosets themselves are not orbits under this action.

The cosets $G/H = \{gH \ | \ g \in G\}$ are actually the orbits of the *right action* of $H$ on $G$ by multiplication.  $G$ also has a left action on itself by multiplication and these actions are compatable, i.e., $g\cdot(x\cdot h) = (g\cdot x)\cdot h$ for all $g, x \in G$ and $h \in H$.  Whenever you have a set $X$ with a left $G$ action and a right $H$ action which are compatible in this way, then $G$ acts on the $H$-orbits $X/H$ and if two $H$-orbits in $X/H$ lie in the same $G$-orbit (of the action of $G$ on $X/H$) then indeed they will be the same size.

So you could say that the reason the partitions of $G$ into cosets of $H$ are all the same is precisely because the action of $G$ on these cosets is transitive.

Comment: @user119615: Added a bit more info to explain what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jim's answer, a group $G$ acts on its elements by conjugation; we have the map $\cdot^g : G \to G$ where $x \mapsto x^g = g^{-1}xg$.

It's definitely not the case that conjugacy classes all need to have the same size.